# How to see audit logs on kubernetes in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How to see audit logs on kubernetes in GKE? I can see that nodes are added automatically and deleted also. I want to see the audit logs for these nodes in gke cluster.

Comment: I can see that nodes are added automatically and deleted also.  -- How do you check it?  From logs or by observing the cluster size ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request right, you are wondering on [how to enable](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/linux-auditd-logging) verbose operating system audit logs on Google KubernetesEngine.

This chapter of [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging) provides info on how to access Audit Logs.

Hope that helps.